# How to count related word from a list of word separated with comma

Tags: php, arrays, tags

Hello i am trying to count number of related word from a list of words that are separated with comma. In short i am try to work with tags and i want to get the first word and count it similar words. For example:

```
$words = 'php, codes, php, script, php, chat.';
```

In the above example the word PHP appears three time any possibly way to catch them in sperate form to out put this:

- php - 3
- codes - 1
- script - 1

Mean while i was able to loop out the words from my db and separate each of them as a link but i also want to use them as tag references to count each tags words found.

Comment: Is there anything you've tried?

Comment: *"Mean while i was able to loop out the words from my db and separate each of them as a link"* Do you mean they are stored like this in the DB ?

Comment: Yest there were store with comma separate in the DB

Comment: This is a poorly designed DB. You're losing the benefit of using indexes. Think about [DB normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: `explode` & `array_count_values` can easily get you there. (Well, almost, you might want to throw in a `trim` to get rid of that trailing dot first.)

Comment: The above data where catch as tags input from a form with mean they will be separated by comma. I was able to explode this word and and get them seprated to use in form of links that work. I just hope i coud be ablue to count the related words as i outline int my questions.

Comment: @CBroe you have show me a light of array_count_values thank you very much you seem to understand what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way that works with PHP 7.2+:

```
<?php

$words = rtrim('php, codes, php, script, php, chat.',".");
$exploded = explode(", ",$words);
$arrCount = array_count_values($exploded);
var_dump($arrCount);
```

live code: https://3v4l.org/BNXjf

The code trims off the period punctuating the string.  Then it explodes the string into the array $exploded using a 2-character string composed of a comma followed by a space character.  Then the code defly uses the PHP 7 function array_count_values which creates a new array in this case $arrCount and this array's keys are the values of $exploded and its values are the number of times each value appears in $exploded as the var_dump() of $arrCount reveals.